# Meaning of ' ' sql in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

what is the difference between two following queries ?

```
WHERE DeviceID = '1339750411' and DT.McId = '40'

WHERE DeviceID = '1339750411' and DT.McId = 40
```

Both above query limitations return the same result.

`McId` is integer value in my SQL Server database.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Single quotes (`' '`) denote **string literals** in T-SQL.

The first `WHERE` clause has `'40'` as a **string**, but SQL Server will automagically convert that to `int` when comparing against an `int` column (`DT.McId`).

Option #2 is better: if it's an `int` column, there's no point in comparing against a string - it's an `int`, so treat it like an `int`.

Option #2 will not incur an implicit conversion and thus is better in terms of performance

Comment: Just to be clear, a single implicit conversion from a string variable to a number isn't going to be a big deal for performance. Implicit conversion usually refers to having to convert every value in the database to match the variable's datatype, which wouldn't happen here.

Comment: @BrentOzar: agreed - in this case here, they're will most likely be only very few comparisons - but it's just a generally bad idea to compare `int` values against string literals.